# How to set a shell variable containing a single dash '-'?

Tags: zsh, variable, echo

How do I set a variable in <strike>Bash</strike> Zsh with a single dash (`-`)?

None of these work:

```
x=-
x=\-
x='-'
```

EDIT: this seems to work fine in Bash, I was testing this with echo in Zsh which doesn't work.

Comment: All of those assignments work. Perhaps your problem is elsewhere. How are you using that variable?

Comment: I'm an idiot, I was testing this with echo in zsh.. thanks

Comment: Answer your own question explaining what was going on, for later reference.

Comment: @vonbrand, [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/170373) comes to mind. Subbeh, you're not an idiot, it's just that `echo` sucks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with echo. The variable is assigned correctly but had to be used with `echo - $x` instead.